# iPhone mapview region zoom not working properly

Tags: iphone, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = 50;
location.longitude = -50;
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 5, 5);

region.center=location;
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];
[mapView setDelegate:self];

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
[self setView:mapView];
```

It will be zoomed in, but zoomed in too far.
So if I change it to this:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = 50;
location.longitude = -50;
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 200, 200);

region.center=location;
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:TRUE];
[mapView setDelegate:self];

[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
[self setView:mapView];
```

It will be zoomed out all the way. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You know that lat/long 50,-50 is in the Atlantic Ocean and that the distances are in meters?

Answer (score 1):

It was because it called the method too early in the execution. I added a viewWillLoad that will be called after it is loaded and then everything worked properly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't numbers between 5 and 200 for the 2nd and 3rd arguments of `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance` make the region zoomed in an intermediate amount? The [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance) say that those arguments are the distance in each direction to include in the region.